# Re-mapping localhost in Windows on Parallels for Mac

Tags: parallels

I have just started using Parallels for Mac, and am attempting to debug a locally running web application on my host MacOS machine.

I have figured out that I can connect to the my host via 10.211.55.2 in the browser in my virtual windows machine.

What I'd like to do is to instead connect via localhost and have this routed through to the 10.211.55.2 ip instead.

I tried editing my windows hosts file with an `10.211.55.2     localhost` entry but this made no difference.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

localhost is hardcoded in many libraries. In theory it should be possible, but it would break a lot of things, including not being able to boot up the system. Connections to localhost are used frequently for interprocess communication throughout the system, so there's more to it then you using it for testing websites. Just go with another name.